# How to pass a JavaScript variable to JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

As I mentioned in the title I want to pass a Javascript variable to JQuery. I spend the whole day to find out a way but got nothing. I tried to using ajax to pass a variable to PHP then I can get the response data. But when I want to pass it into highcharts, it didn't work, could anyone show me how to do this? I will be very appreciated.

```
//this is the ajax I used to send the request to PHP , I can get the data in data_ajax.
function chooseCategory(mat_id){
            var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "test.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
             data_ajax = ajax.responseText;
             alert(data_ajax);}
                }

                ajax.send("id=" + material_id);
        }

    //this is part of the jquery code, the charts can not get any data from variable data_ajax.
     $(function () {                                            
$('#container3').highcharts({
    ...
    ...
     series: [{  type: 'line', name: '#numbers：', data: data_ajax
```

Comment: JQuery IS javascript! instead of alert, call the highcharts where you have the alert. You are now calling the highcharts on load of the page and not after the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on Ajax, and also on jQuery.

Try this first

```
function chooseCategory(mat_id){
  $.post("test.php",{"id":mat_id},function(data) {
    window.console && console.log(data);
  });
}
```

then when you are happy try the highcharts which has to be loaded of course

```
function chooseCategory(mat_id){
  $.post("test.php",{"id":mat_id},function(data) {
    $('#container3').highcharts({
     series: [{  "type":"line", "name": "#numbers", "data": data }]
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: function chooseCategory(mat_id){
     $.post("test.php",{"id":mat_id},function(data_ajax) { 
   alert(data_ajax);                            
      $('#container3').highcharts({   //I still can not get the data into the container3

Comment: Ah, I found the reason, when we get the Json data from PHP, it is string type, but highcharts require int. After I use JSON.PARSE(data) to transform the data, it works well. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Ajax call is asynchronous, you need to wait for it to complete before loading Highcharts.  To do this you typically use a callback.  Put the chart-loading code into a function "loadCharts(data)", and invoke that from inside the Ajax handler.  Something like this:

```
function chooseCategory(mat_id){
    // ...

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            data_ajax = ajax.responseText;
            alert(data_ajax);
            loadCharts(data_ajax);
        }
    };
}

function loadCharts(data_ajax)
    $('#container3').highcharts({ ... });
}
```

Comment: I did what you told me, but I still can not get the variable inside the container, I don't know what is the reason. anyway, Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a function which calles *highcharts*.

```
var drawChart = function(data_ajax) {
   $('#container3').highcharts({
      ...
      ...
      series: [{  type: 'line', name: '#numbers：', data: data_ajax
   });
}
```

And then instead of alert the data simply call the function:

```
drawChart(data_ajax)
```